# $http in angularjs does not work

Tags: angularjs

I have a piece of Code in angularjs. If I hard code the value of http response it is displaying the response when I use the http method in angularjs it is not displaying. Whenever request sends to server i get error function. I dont know where I am wrong. Here is the code

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  angular
    .module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache'])
    .controller('DemoCtrl', DemoCtrl);

  function DemoCtrl($timeout, $q, $log, $http, $scope) {
    var self = this;

    self.simulateQuery = false;
    self.isDisabled = false;

    self.repos = loadAll();
    self.querySearch = querySearch;
    self.selectedItemChange = selectedItemChange;
    self.searchTextChange = searchTextChange;


    function querySearch(query) {
      var results = query ? self.repos.filter(createFilterFor(query)) : self.repos,
        deferred;
      if (self.simulateQuery) {
        deferred = $q.defer();
        $timeout(function() {
          deferred.resolve(results);
        }, Math.random() * 1000, false);
        return deferred.promise;
      } else {
        return results;
      }
    }

    function searchTextChange(text) {
      $log.info('Text changed to ' + text);
    }

    function selectedItemChange(item) {
      $log.info('Item changed to ' + JSON.stringify(item));
    }


    function loadAll() {
      $log.info('test');

      var repos;
      repos = [];

      $http.get('http://melkban24.ir/city/json/2').success(function(response) {
        $scope.repos = response.data;

      });

      return repos.map(function(repo) {
        repo.value = repo.nameCity.toLowerCase();
        $log.info(repo.value);
        return repo;
      });
    }


    function createFilterFor(query) {
      var lowercaseQuery = angular.lowercase(query);

      return function filterFn(item) {
        return (item.value.indexOf(lowercaseQuery) === 0);
      };

    }
  }
})();
```

Comment: Tell us what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it.

Answer (score 1):

`$http.get()` is asynchronous, so the `.success()` callback won't be called until after your function has returned. That means `loadAll()` cannot return the data. Try not to confuse `$scope.repos` with the local variable `repos` as they are quite different things.

Don't use the deprecated `.success()` method at all. Use `.then()` as it will return a promise which is compatible with other uses of promises in angular.

Move the map code inside the `.then` callback and if you want `loadAll()` to return anything make it return the promise that `.then()` returns. That way anything that calls `loadAll()` can wait on the promise to complete.

```
function loadAll() {
     return $http.get('http://melkban24.ir/city/json/2').then(function(result){
        var repos = result.data.data;
        return repos.map(function (repo) {
           repo.value = repo.nameCity.toLowerCase();
           return repo;
        });
        $scope.repos = repos;
      });
}
```

Now you have two ways to get at the data: it will appear as the `repos` value in the scope once it has been retrieved. If used in an angular template the page will show the new data. Or call `loadAll()` and use the promise to get at the returned data:

```
loadAll().then(function(repos) { ... });
```

You should also consider including code for the case where `$http.get()` fails. Pass it an error callback as well.

Also, as @Rakeschand points out in the comments, the next step should be to move all the `$http` code out of the controller and into a service. You still end up calling a function that returns a promise, but code to convert the received data into the data you actually want can be removed from the controller.

Comment: In addition, one should create a external service for doing http stuff